# unable to perform a successful svn revert

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am attempting to rollback a bunch of revisions in my trunk.  I am using tortisesvn 1.8.10 and in a working copy of my trunk I display the svn log from the root folder.  From the svn log dialog I select the revision that I was to revert to and right click and select "Revert to this revision".  A svn window is displayed and the command at the top says "Merging revision HEAD-9046 of https://svn.mycompanyy/svn/psc/trunk@HEAD into C:\workingcopy, ignoring abcestry
Reverse merging 35107 through 9047 C:\workingcopy"

The problem I have is that this command never seems to yield the same results from one run to the next.  I get tree conflicts displayed that I cannot take any action on and certain folders are left in a incomplete state.  Perhaps it reverts some portion of the folder structure and not the entire structure.  I have another workingcopy that I have checked-out to the revision that I am reverting to and when I compare them they do not agree.

One revision in particular was a complete restructure of the code base from the root folder on down.  Is there a preferred way to run this?  Should I run this in command line mode and not tortiseSVN.  If so, what is the actual merge command line that Tortise is running under the covers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `Merging revision HEAD-9046 of https://svn.mycompanyy/svn/psc/trunk@HEAD into C:\workingcopy, 
>      ignoring ancestry Reverse merging 35107 through 9047 C:\workingcopy`

Are you really trying to roll back over 26,000 revisions? That seems a way bit excessive. That's 74% of your commits.

You are better off making a branch at the point you want to rollback and work off that branch -- at least for a while. You can decide whether or not you want *any* or your work on trunk in that new branch and cherry pick merge just those revisions.

Once you have a better handle on your development, you can diff your branch and trunk, and then do a *patch* of the diff to your trunk to make it look like the branch.

Comment: well, you tell me, almost all of those revisions have taken place in development branches.  In the trunk, it jumps from 9046 to 35067 and then there are about five revision in total on top of the 9046 in trunk.  The 9046 revision are as a result of doing an svnadmin load from a dump of code from another repo.  The big issue I think is that one of the revision is moving the entire code base which is huge to a sub-folder under the root called code. But I'm new to svn so perhaps I'm unclear in what it is really doing under the covers.

Comment: So, there are only five trunk revisions? Do a clean checkout. Use the command line and use the `svn -c -$rev merge .` command where `$rev` is the revision you want to back out. Back out from highest to lowest. This way, you can do this one revision at a time. You shouldn't be getting any conflicts since you're backing off the last revision, then the one before that.

Comment: If I wanted to rollback a series of revisions one at a time without committing each one do indicate the interim revision for each step? For example: 
1) svn merge -r HEAD:150 .
2) svn merge -r 150: 140  .
3) svn merge -r 140: 100 .
In this case I want the end result to be to go from HEAD to revision 100.

Comment: Yes, you can do a series of _reverse merges_ without doing a commit. In fact, you can use `--dry-run` just to make sure that a particular rollback wont' give you a problem. You can do all the revisions at once via `-r` or multiple `-c`, but since there are only five revisions, you might as well do it one at a time to give you more control what's going on. Word of warning: Rollbacks don't affect `svn:mergeinfo`. If you want to add these revisions back in at a later time, you have to _rollback_ your _rollback_. Use a good comment which includes the revisions rolled back, so you can find it.

Comment: At the risk of getting dinged.  It appears than the issue we were running into was the fact that the revert kept failing in the middle with a message: Error ra_serf: the server sent a truncated HTTP response body.  We would restart it and it would complete, but the results were always different when compared to a working copy that was updated to the revision we were reverting to.  I found a suggestion about setting the TIMEOUT in the svn server's httpd.conf file and restarting the server. Once set, I was successfully revert to the desired revision without the command failing in the middle.